# Cannot refresh provisioning profiles in Xcode after changing Apple ID password

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I am an individual developer signed up with both the iOS and Mac development programs.  My account is paid up and in good standing.  Recently when logging into iTunes Connect, I was told that my password was too old and was asked to change it, which I did.  I also decided to set up two factor authentication on my Apple ID while I was at it.

Unfortunately I can now no longer refresh my provisioning profiles in Xcode (5.0.2 (5A3005)) I get the error

```
An unexpected error occurred. Please try again.  If the problem persists, please contact Apple Developer Program Support.
https://developer.apple.com/support
```

(before you ask, yes I remembered to change the password in Xcode preferences)

In Console I see the following error:

```
12/10/13 12:51:30.769 AM Xcode[34131]:  DeveloperPortal: Completed request ABD4EE26-85F8-4053-BD5E-DFCF0E451638 (failure): {
    "DTDK_Platform" = ios;
    creationTimestamp = "2013-12-10 08:51:30 +0000";
    protocolVersion = P5Y9MG;
    requestId = "ABD4EE26-85F8-4053-BD5E-DFCF0E451638";
    requestUrl = "http://developerservices2.apple.com/services/P5Y9MG/ios/listProvisioningProfiles.action?clientId=XABBG36SBA";
    responseId = "a035c476-1a3d-40c2-bf69-d32109f9ee3c";
    resultCode = "-1";
    resultString = ObjectNotFoundException;
    teamId = TJHY9SDE3V;
    userLocale = "en_US";
    userString = "An unexpected error occurred. Please try again.  If the problem persists, please contact Apple Developer Program Support.\nhttps://developer.apple.com/support";
}
```

I have tried deleting my account from Xcode Preferences and re-adding it from scratch, but that does not help at all.  FYI I can log in to the developer.apple.com website just fine, access the member center, certs/IDs/profiles, forums, etc.  No problems.  I can also log into iTunes Connect perfectly.  My certificates and private keys are all in Keychain Access and are valid (i.e. not expired, etc.)

I'm at my wit's end here.  Does anyone have any ideas as to what's going on here?  Is this something that I need to use one of my 2 developer technical support incidents on?

Comment: as i remember, setting up 2 factor auth could need up to 3 days to be completed. Perhaps thats the problem. Did you tried to delete the correspondending logins from your keychain tool?

Comment: It has been more than 3 days since I set up TFA.  Plus, I can still access other Apple services fine (e.g. make iTunes purchases, log in to the developer portal, etc.)

Comment: I am having this problem as well, but looking at the console I see something different: it looks like I'm getting an html page saying that the site is undergoing maintenance and xcode is trying to parse it as a plist.

Comment: Unfortunately as it turned out in my case, I had to contact Developer Technical Support... there must have been something wrong with my account.